# Insert output back into Nested For Loop Python 3

Tags: python, loops, nested, output, feedback

I working on a project and i would like to feedback my output from a nested loop back into the loop. I have 2 For Loop I would like to feed the output of the inner loop back in but i'm not sure on how to do that. The outter loop takes the word i'm searching for and the inner loop i'm adding the missing words. After each loop i would like to feed the updated output back in the loop.

Thanks for what ever help you can give me.

Example:

column_header_single = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]

addstring_sign = ["Monday was a snowing day", "Wednesday no snow"]

```
string_test1a = []
string_test2a = []

for gi in (column_header_single):
    dictlines1 = (gi)

    for loopblock in (addstring_sign):

        if addstring_sign.count(dictlinesa1) < 1:
           string_test1a.append(loopblock[:len(loopblock)] + dictlines1 + '\n' + loopblock[len(loopblock):])

        else:
           string_test2a.append(loopblock)
        addstring_sign = string_test1a + string_test2a
    break
```

OUTPUT - addstring_sign = ["Monday was a snowing day Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday", 
              "Wednesday no snow Monday Tuesday Thursday Friday"]

Comment: So for each iteration of the inner loop you want give a result to the outer loop?

Comment: so for example the OUTPUT - addstring_sign = [Monday was a snowing day , Wednesday no snow Monday ] --- After the first loop i would get this output --- I would like to put that output back into the inner loop. The outter loop would have "Monday" The inner loop would have  "Monday was a snowing day , Wednesday no snow"

Comment: I think best practice would be to put your loop into a generator function then. The generator will `yield` a result and you can feed that result back to the generator.

Comment: Tekay37 - Thanks for giving me some ideas .... Is there a website you would recommend

Comment: I did learn python generators via Corey Schafers youtube videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD05uGo_sVI
And there is a PyCon talk about generators on youtube.

Comment: This stackoverflow link works for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410832/cascading-for-loop-outputs-is-there-a-better-python-3-way?noredirect=1#comment83813857_48410832