# Cascading FOR loop outputs is there a better python 3 way

Tags: python, string, for-loop, nested-loops, cascade

Right now, I have a word that I'm search for in a larger string if the word is not found then I insert the word in the larger sting. The output of the first FOR loop is cascaded into a second FOR loop.

This work's ok, with one or two but if I had 100's or 1000's of searchs it would be a pain to do this each time is there a better python 3 way?

As you can see from the example I'm looking for Monday in the first string monday is there so it just skips the second string does not have Monday so it adds monday in. I would have a new list at that point. So I put the output of the first loop into the input of the second loop to update the input.

Example:

`Input: - addstring_sign = ["Monday was a snowing day", "Wednesday no snow"]`

`string_test1 = [] 
string_test2 = []
dictlines1 = ("Monday")`

```
for loopblock in (addstring_sign):

    if addstring_sign.count(dictlines1) < 1:
       string_test1.append(loopblock[:len(loopblock)] + dictlines1 +'\n'+loopblock[len(loopblock):])

    else:
       string_test2.append(loopblock)
    addstring_sign1 = string_test1 + string_test2
```

`OutPut of addstring_sign1 = ["Monday was a snowing day", "Wednesday no snow Monday"]`

`string_test3 = []
string_test4 = []
dictlines2 = ("Tuesday")`

```
for loopblock2 in (addstring_sign1):

    if addstring_sign.count(dictlines2) < 1:
       string_test3.append(loopblock2[:len(loopblock2)] + dictlines2 +'\n'+loopblock2[len(loopblock2):])

    else:
       string_test4.append(loopblock)
    addstring_sign2 = string_test3 + string_test4`
```

`output of addstring_sign2 = ["Monday was a snowing day Tuesday", "Wednesday no snow Monday Tuesday"]`

I am lost on how to make this more efficient.

Comment: So if the word is not in your string, it should _always_ just be tagged on to the end of that string? I ask because I'm not sure I have understood the indexing correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is right ... It is added to the end of the string  - So new example if we added Wednesday the output would be - addstring_sign3 = ["Monday was a snowing day Tuesday Wednesday", "Wednesday no snow Monday Tuesday"]

Comment: I'm still wondering whether I've understood your approach properly. Why do you keep supplying `dictlines` individually? I'm not sure how to set up proper timings for my answer against your approach.

Comment: I tried a nested loop before which I had in a list format but it would over ride the output but it would work if i feeded it in one by one and cascade the output. I'm going to try you new way and see if it work for my bigger project.

Comment: You're welcome, I just suddenly hit a wall and wondered whether there was some practical limitation that stopped me developing my answer. So, if you get the correct output from me supplying `dictlines` as a list, e.g. `dictlines = ['Monday', 'Tuesday']` then there is no limitation stopping you from doing it this way?

Comment: For my bigger project I have 76 dictlines and 1306 addstring_sign in a list format .... diclines is single words and addstring_sign is a paragraphs of text.

Comment: Wow you're a genius it looks like it is working.  Thank you

Comment: It can still go faster, I'm working on code to tie up my answer

Comment: Sorry, newborn in the house so took me ages to review my code and I couldn't complete longer tests, but converting to a `set` will probably give another huge speed-up to the approach I originally gave.

Comment: Intresting ok going to read up on set .... Thank roganjosh you been super helpful

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, I think the below approaches are much cleaner than what you're currently doing and possibly appreciably faster (I need some time to set up proper test cases, to be added shortly).

```
addstring_sign = ["Monday was a snowing day", "Wednesday no snow"]
dictlines = ['Monday', 'Tuesday']

string_test1 = []
for string in addstring_sign:
    missing_strings = ' '.join([item for item in dictlines if item not in string])
    string_test1.append('{} {}'.format(string, missing_strings))

# Or a list comprehension for the same thing, probably not much faster
string_test2 = ['{} {}'.format(string, 
                ' '.join([item for item in dictlines if item not in string])) 
                for string in addstring_sign]
```

The next thing to do to speed this up is to convert `dictlines` to a `set` for larger problems. This is done simply with:

```
dictlines = set(dictlines)
```

Which will give you O(1) lookup - this will become more and more significant as `dictlines` grows in size. I struggled to get your existing code into an approach I could test on a larger scale but was unable. However, you can see that even with this tiny example, and without a `set` (here it makes little difference) that my initial approach is faster than your existing one:

```
%timeit my_for_loop(addstring_sign, dictlines)
1.53 µs ± 4.08 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit your_loop(addstring_sign, dictlines)
2.13 µs ± 8.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;**

```
for word in strings:
    sentences = [line if word in line else line + ' ' + word for line in sentences]
```

So you are given a list of **sentences**, of which you need to check if each contains a **string**. When one of them does not, you want to append the string to the sentence.

Let's first look at the second line of code and consider the case where you only have one word to search and append. This list comprehension iterates through your list of sentences then:

1. Checks if the string is in the sentence
2. Appends the string if it isn't in the sentence

At the end of the iterations, it reconstructs the list and assigns it back to the original list.

The first line of code than simply repeat this process for every word you wish to search and append.

Comment: Yes, That is right pinealan ... thank you for the help .... This is list comprehension right ?.... need to learn this ASAP it looks super powerful.

Comment: Yes, this is list comprehension. Edited the answer to give a longer explanation.